# Firebase error: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled must be made before any other usage of FIRDatabase instance

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to enable offline data with my firebase database. Unfortunately when running this code, it tells me that 'Calls to setPersistenceEnabled must be made before any other usage of FIRDatabase instance.' I believe this is because firebase calls are asynchronous, but I can't figure out how to fix the issue.

from my AppDelegate:

```
        //Firebase database
        let myDatabase = Database.database().reference()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        //Firebase
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true

        //check if user is already logged in
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signedIn")

        } else {
            // No user is signed in. Directs to Login/Register view.
        }

        return true
    }
```

I've tried commenting out the check user login portion in case Auth.auth() was messing it up, but it didn't fix it. Should I be putting some of these things elsewhere instead of my AppDelegate?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does the code include the line `let myDatabase = Database.database().reference()`? Seems like `myDatabase` doesn't get used.

Comment: I use it elsewhere. I accidentally put it there right before pasting it here. It's supposed to be declared at the top of AppDelegate.

Comment: You should remove the line "let myDatabase = Database.database().reference()" from AppDelegate."Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true" should be the first to execute before accessing database as the error says.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the database before initializing Firebase. Remove the let myDatabase from your AppDelegate and use them in your ViewControllers instead.

Your error is not related to persistence but is caused by calling a Firebase database before it is setup in your AppDelegate.